# CV2 Install Docker Windows (OpenCV)

Tags: windows, opencv, docker, jupyter

I installed Docker on windows to support tensorflow. As I am running Python on docker based jupyter, I am facing issue with one of my code as it needs OpenCV module. For installing any other required modules I just simply used the terminal present on Jupyter Docker and used pip install, but I am not able to install opencv through the same method.

Can somebody please help with a way to install Opencv in the Docker based jupyter?

Comment: I never used docker jupyter , but if you're facing issue with dependencies inside a container i think a solution will be create a dockerfile derived from your docker image , install all opencv required packages , and build and compile opencv on image build.. or run docker exec -it container bash ( and install all nedeed dependencies )

Comment: Hi Joaquin, Thanks for your reply.. I just found one more query regarding this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862589/install-opencv-in-a-docker-container.. in this the solution is to use the dockerfile                                                                                       


FROM continuumio/anaconda
EXPOSE 5000

ADD . /code-directory
WORKDIR code-directory
RUN conda install opencv

CMD ["python", "run-code.py"]


I am not sure how to create and run a docker file.. In the dockerfile window when i tried running these commands its not accepting..

Comment: could you provide the exact  docker based jupyter image are you using? i will take a look to see if we can just add dependencies without create a dockerfile

Comment: Firstly need the exactly docker image you are running , then depending how the image is build you can  "enter" the container running docker exec -it container_name bash , once logged you can try to install required dependencies. Another way is just create a docker image from the image and install all the dependencies , so they will be added at build runtime. I never used docker on windows maybe somethings differ Regards!